# Deploying online shiny app depending on functions within the R folder (inside a package)

Tags: r, shiny, r-package, shinyapps, drat

I have an R package called `foo` that is not uploaded on CRAN but hosted on Github. Within the package, I have, together with standard files and functions within the `R/` folder, a shiny app within the `inst/` folder.
Now, the shiny app use some of the functions of the `foo` package and I can load the package within the `app.R` using `library(foo)` and everything works fine. However when deploying the app online I cannot put `foo` as dependency and I cannot access the `R/` folder (unless I copy the scripts within the `inst/app/` folder. Is there a way to deploy an app within a package that use some of the package functions?

Comment: Assuming you want to continue to use the not-CRAN package, you need to find a way to have it available. One such mechanism is to use the `drat` package, allowing you to use (for example) a github repo as a place to search for R packages; see https://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/drat.html. (To be clear ... the steps for `drat` are not hard, but it takes several steps to do. You must do something that involves creating many ancillary files in order to support the notion of `install.packages("foo", repo="...")` from somewhere other than your personal computer.)

Comment: Alternative, though untested: change what is included in the files manifest (via `rsconnect::deployApp(..., appFileManifest=)`), and either include the `../R/*.R` files, or include the `.tar.gz` package file itself. From there, include code in your shiny app (e.g., in `global.R`) that either sources the `R/*.R` files or installs the `.tar.gz` file.

Comment: I added the [tag:drat] tag since it seems relevant here (you didn't know to add it, understandably). This might attract the attention of its author (Dirk), though your question is not exactly in a good state to do much more than say *"read the documentation and try to use `drat`"*; if you try it and it fails, _then_ a question might be more appropriate when filled out with what you tried and what didn't work.

Comment: thank you @r2evans, the `drat` method seems quite powerful, I have to try it. The `rsconnect::deployApp(..., appFileManifest=)` is not working. Apparently, I cannot reference files that are not on the app path.

Comment: Sorry about that, it isn't in any of my workflows, it's not in my habit pattern, but I thought I'd suggest it in case it could work. I think the `drat` method might be the best way forward for you then. Good luck!

Comment: I've deployed apps as packages by using `devtools::install_github` to install locally before deployment and then shinyapps can also download the package from there and `library(foo)` works as you'd expect